# Is the wing (AKA fender) on a BMW 335d MSport attached by glue?

Tags: bmw, body, repair

I have cracked my wing and discovered that there is glue under the wing as if it has been repaired before. The garage I bought the car from is claiming that it is factory fitted and that BMW use glue to fit wings when they build the cars.

I would like to know if this is true or if the garage I bought the car from are trying to avoid paying for the repair or not can some one confirm please?

I have posted on google groups too but wanted to see if I could get a quicker response here.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.autos.bmw/QG9tMGGO5fo

Comment: Sorry but the edit made is not correct i did not mention any spoiler damage in my question, it is the passenger side front wing.

Comment: I made a slight change that seems to fit better with your intent.  Let me know if that looks like what you expected.  Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: Sounds like foreign terminology to a Brit like me, but to be clear it is the panel above the wheels. Thanks for the welcome :-)

Comment: Can you post a photo to help eliminate any terminology differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manufacturers do sometimes use epoxy resin (or something like that) to attach spoilers and fenders. Mostly because it doesn't require drilling, which is a weak spot where rust can start to form, but also to form a nice aerodynamic seal. But then, you can never trust a secondhand car dealer and it may be that they had stuck on a wing/fender that had come off.

Update: the glue BMW uses is called [BetaLink](http://www.ecstuning.com/ES196859/).

Comment: Ok, so when i say wing i mean the panel in front of the doors, are those called spoilers or am i mistakenly calling it a wing?

Comment: @MrGray isn't talking about the spoiler, he's talking about the front fender.